# How can I find $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$

Tags: statistics

$n=240$ trials with a $6$ sided dice

$X = \#5$'s

$Y = \#6$'s

How do I go about showing that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = -20/3$? I think I need to find $V(X+Y)$ but I'm not sure how. $V(X)=V(Y)=240* 1/6 * 5/6$.

Comment: Consider one throw. $Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=0-\frac 1{36}$. Now multiply by 240.

Comment: @A.S. Is/Are the die/dice fair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the covariance if the die rolled 240 times is fair (or the 240 dice rolled are fair). What if the die/dice is/are not fair?

X and Y are [binomially distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function):

$$P(X=x) = \binom{n}{x}(p_x)^x(1-p_x)^{n-x}$$

$$P(Y=y) = \binom{n}{y}(p_y)^y(1-p_y)^{n-y}$$

$p_x$ and $p_y$ represent the probability of rolling a 5 and a 6, resp.

$$E[X] = np_x = 240p_x \stackrel{if \ fair}{=} 40$$

$$E[Y] = np_y = 240p_y \stackrel{if \ fair}{=} 40$$

Now to compute $Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$ we also need $E[XY]$.

$$E[XY] = \sum_{x=0}^{n}\sum_{y=0}^{n} xy P(X=x, Y=y)$$

I guess $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

$$P(X=x, Y=y)$$

is what you call the [bivariate binomial distribution](http://dspace.uni.lodz.pl:8080/xmlui/bitstream/handle/11089/694/147-157.pdf):

$$P(X=x, Y=y) = \binom{n}{x}\binom{n-x}{y}(p_x)^x(p_y)^y(1-p_x-p_y)^{n-x-y}$$

Note that

$$\binom{n}{x}\binom{n-x}{y} = \frac{n}{(n-x-y)!x!y!}$$

agreeing with the form in the link above, which derives $E[XY]$ to be:

$$E[XY] = n(n-1)p_xp_y \stackrel{if \ fair}{=} (240)(239)(1/6)(1/6)$$

$$\therefore, Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] \stackrel{if \ fair}{=} -240(1/6)(1/6)$$